# Undefined reference to ''__netcdf_MOD_nf90_"

Tags: parallel-processing, fortran, linker-errors, undefined-reference, netcdf

I'm trying to build a Fortran model with Parallel IO (1.7.2) included. But I got numerous errors like these:

```
pionfwrite_mod.F90:(.text+0x1bad): undefined reference to `nfmpi_iput_vara_'
pionfwrite_mod.F90:(.text+0x21ad): undefined reference to `__netcdf_MOD_nf90_put_var_1d_fourbyteint'
pionfwrite_mod.F90:(.text+0x22a9): undefined reference to `__netcdf_MOD_nf90_inquire_variable'
pionfwrite_mod.F90:(.text+0x27e5): undefined reference to `__netcdf_MOD_nf90_put_var_1d_fourbyteint'
pionfwrite_mod.F90:(.text+0x2ad7): undefined reference to `__netcdf_MOD_nf90_put_var_1d_fourbyteint'
```

I googled and found some possible solutions, for example, https://www.myroms.org/wiki/Frequently_Asked_Questions#Errors_at_link_time, but I still cannot solve my problem.

Questions: is this a library linking problem? if not, could you please give me some suggestions on how to debug? If so, could you please share the detailed steps on how to link the library? Thank you.

*Environment libraries: PnetCDF 1.8.1, netCDF 4.5.1, Parallel IO 1.7.2, gcc 7.1.1, openmpi-2.0.2-2.fc26.x86_64*

Comment: Yea, it is a linking error. You must link the NetCDF library. So how do you link? Do you link with NetCDF? How exactly? Which command caused the error? We need to see the details. It is the same as with your last question. How can we say what 's wrong when you don't tell us what are you doing?

Comment: Please use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questiins. Fortran 90 is just one old version. If you are a student it might be even older than you.

Comment: Make sure all the libraries you wish to link precede other libraries of the same name in your link path, e.g., so that the fortran netCDF library compiled with parallel options precedes the fortran netCDF library compiled without parallel options. Often the LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable is crucial.

Comment: Thanks to VladimirF and Charlie Zender for confirming the error and suggestions.

Comment: It is better to post a solution as an answer, so that the question is not left unanswered. I recommend you to do that, so that you can build reputation here. If you don't want, I will post it as a community wiki answer later.

Comment: Thanks! I posted my solution as a separate answer. Hope this is clear now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by checking the library path and install earlier versions of netcdf and pnetcdf in local folders.

The makefile from this MPAS model sets netcdf path and library as follows:

```
ifneq "$(NETCDF)" ""
        CPPINCLUDES += -I$(NETCDF)/include
        FCINCLUDES += -I$(NETCDF)/include
        LIBS += -L$(NETCDF)/lib
        NCLIB = -lnetcdf
        NCLIBF = -lnetcdff
        ...
endif
```

while for linux F26, it seems the netcdf installed using DNF (not sure if DNF is the reason though) does not build a separate folder to put all related files under $NETCDF, the related files are instead installed under /usr/local/include and /usr/lib64

```
$ which netcdf
/usr/local/include/netcdf

$ which libnetcdf.so.11
/usr/lib64/libnetcdf.so.11
```

which leads to the error in model build.

I was trying to modify the makefile but it led to numerous other errors. So I kept the makefile unchanged, and built separate netcdf and pnetcdf from sources in separate local folders, and use the corresponding paths to rebuild PIO and to compile the model, which solved my problem. Note that these pnetcdf and netcdf paths should also be added into ~/.bashrc as LD_LIBRARY_PATH for MPAS model run. More instructions can be found here: http://www2.mmm.ucar.edu/projects/mpas/tutorial/UK2015/index.html.